# Преобразование данных строки TableView в переменную String

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть таблица с данными `LinkTable`, в нужном столбце `LinkColumn` хранятся ссылки на документы которые я могу открыть, беда только в том, что я не понимаю как для моего метода `openFile` понять, какую строку необходимо считывать, для открытия нужного файла, к примеру вот метод `openFile`

```
   public void openFile(){
        String fileName = mainController.getLinkTable(). //тут я пытаюсь получить таблицу, потом понять какая строка у меня выделена, 
//что бы записать в переменную String, с помощью которой я бы открыл файл. Если в String
//сразу указать путь файла, он откроется.
        Desktop desktop = null;
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        }

        try {
            desktop.open(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

класс Controller

```
@FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Инициализация таблицы.
        linkTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Attachment> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                    linkTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().openFile();
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
```

Comment: Не смогу помочь с кодом, давно избегаю TableView, но у вас есть строка, которая знает о пути к нужному файлу, так пускай она сама по нажатию и открывает документ?

Comment: @Maxim у меня сейчас в методе `initialize` прописано условие, что если я по строке два раза кликаю, то у меня срабатывает метод, но из-за того, что моя таблица записывается путем `private TableView<Attachment> linkTable;`, метод я могу присвоить пока что только из класса `Attachment`, а там стандартные методы чтения какая строка выделена не срабатывает, и я сейчас разбираюсь, как грамотно вызвать класс из контроллера, код сейчас приложу для понимания